# Can you assign unique thread ids and access thread from external program?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am currently implementing a program that requires me to handle threads and process.

**IDEA:**

1. There are multiple java processes running and each process may have multiple threads. 
   Current java implementation is such that thread ids in java is unique for a particular process but not within the processes. So is there a way I could implement a unique thread ids among multiple processes?
2. Also, I need to implement an external java program that monitors these threads. By monitoring I mean, depending upon some logic I need to notify a particular thread(using unique thread id) regarding an event. Is there a way that I can access thread from external program. If yes how?
3. Are there any other solutions to implement the similar idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you mean "unique within a particular process but not _across_ different processes".

Comment: You will get much better answers if you describe the problem you wish to solve, rather than your solution. I can't see a good reason that you would *ever* expose an actual thread to the outside world. Instead, I would expose something that the thread will access (eg, a JMX bean that contains a flag for the thread to read).

Comment: @aasmumnd no...i mean I need uniqueness in thread ids throughout the application among all process instances. 
@parsifal i believe this is what i need because it is part of a much bigger application. This is a small module of a larger case.

Comment: @prap19: I referred to the sentence where you described what Java actually does (which is to _not_ have unique thread ids across processes) - I understood that you _need_ what Java does not provide, namely unique thread ids across processes. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a concatenation of the process id and the thread id to uniquely identify a thread - for instance, thread `23` in process `7038` could be identified as `7038:23`. This has the advantage that given a thread identifier, you can tell which process the thread belongs to.

I doubt that it is possible for one process to control the threads of another. You probably need to use some form of inter-process communication, such as [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html), named pipes, or TCP. Each process should probably have one thread that waits for an incoming message, parses it, and notifies the appropriate thread based on the contents of the message.

A *very* simple example of what a TCP-based solution might look like: Every worker process has a thread that listens for TCP connections from the monitoring process; it is expected that when the monitoring process connects, it will write one line containing the id of a thread in this worker process. The worker process must keep e.g. a `HashMap` that maps thread ids to `Thread` objects.

```
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(6789);
while (true) {
    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    BufferedReader socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                      connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
    String line = socketReader.readLine();
    int threadId = Integer.parseInt(line);
    // Now, use threadId to locate the appropriate thread 
    // and send a notification to it.
}
```

There should probably also be a way for the monitoring process to ask a worker process for all its thread ids. The worker process can simply maintain a list of process ids (and which port each process listens to) and, for each process id, a list of the thread ids inside that process.

By the way, as @parsifal said, it would be interesting to know what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: can you elaborate about it a bit?

Comment: @prap19: Which part of it? (And what kind of elaboration - was there something you didn't understand, or do you want code, ...?)

Comment: You mentioned RMI, named pipes and TCP. So can you explain 1 of the methods that I can relate it with my problem.

Comment: thank you for ur explanation, that was quite understandable. But this implies each process will listen to different unique port and this can be an issue in scalability. how this can be resolved using a similar implementation using TCP?

Comment: @prap19: How many such processes do you expect to have? I would assume that a modern machine can handle thousands of TCP listeners without problems (that's a guess, though; I haven't actually tried it).

Comment: hmm i believe you are right. I am not sure as of now the number of processes that will be created. I will definitely try this method now.